# JS Knex: getting foreign keys for a table

Tags: javascript, database, foreign-keys, knex.js

I want to drop some tables using '[knex](http://knexjs.org/)' but I have an error `Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails` when I try to drop table with foreign key:

```
knex.schema.dropTableIfExists(name);
```

I can use [dropForeign()](http://knexjs.org/#Schema-dropForeign) function to drop foreign key but I need to know foreign key name.

How can I get foreign key names using 'knex'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual foreign key index naming format in knex is : tableName_columnName_foreign.
Eg: If you have in table `chat` a foreign key named `visitor_id` then its index name will be : `chat_visitor_id_foreign`

That said,you wouldn't need this, unless someone has explicitly overridden the default foreign key name. In that case , search for it in the migration file or look it up in the database .